# Physically shutdown Raspberry Pi without shell access

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I forgot my password, so I cannot use `sudo halt`.

How can I safely shut down my Raspberry Pi so I can remove the SD card?

Comment: I could upload PHP using an IDE with an encrypted password, and asked if I could PHP to shut it down here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452694/showdown-server-using-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shutdown command requires root permissions. If you no longer know your root password, you have no other option than to pull the power cord and accept the (very, very low) risk of causing damage.

My biggest concern would be any filesystems you have mounted as read-write.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  Ended up doing just that!  Now I need to figure out how I can insert the tiny SD card in a PC.  I've seen adapters, and am trying to find some other device which uses one (maybe my iPhone?).

Comment: Do the raspberry pi's accept sysrq commands?

Comment: @CanadianLuke  Don't know.  Ended up just yanking the power.  We will see :)